# i cant get the imei number from my uid.imei. the code is below and i am having an error. Cordova imei plugin is not installing

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

[This is the error i encouter while installing cordova imei plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lgGY.png)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error, problem is the plugin itself. It is not well formed. Instead you can use [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid/) plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uid
npm install --save @ionic-native/uid
```

which should work as expected.

Comment: i have done this too and after using uid.imei its not reponding. it still gives me an error in the code.Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available

Comment: It is normal because you need to test it in your phone, these plugins are supported only by smartphones, you can test them in emulator or browser.

Comment: i have tested it on oreo device but still it is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: async getImei() {
    const { hasPermission } = await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
      this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
    );

    if (!hasPermission) {
      const result = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
      );

      if (!result.hasPermission) {
        throw new Error('Permissions required');
      }

      // ok, a user gave us permission, we can get him identifiers after restart app
      return;
    }

        return this.uid.IMEI;

Comment: the returned value is null here or give me an error

Comment: It is returning null on first time launch

Comment: Null in some devices also